# Parametric arrays length in Julia's Composite Types

Tags: julia

I am using Julia's [StrPack](https://strpackjl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module to read binary data from files.

To read a list of 100 values, a use the following `struct`:

```
@struct type MyType
    values::Array{Float64}[100]
end
```

and it works fine.

However, I was wondering if there's a way to parameterize the array's length. Julia's parametric types lets you only change inner types (that is, in the example above, I could replace Float64 with another type).

I also tried this:

```
length=100
@struct type MyType
    values::Array{Float64}[length]
end
```

which gives this error:

```
ERROR: TypeError: Test: in type definition, expected Type{T}, got Array{Float64,1}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: At this point, array dimension is parameterized, but array length is not. There is some discussion around a special array type for fixed size arrays, but AFAIK no one has stepped up yet to take the task on. The discussion starts [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/5857)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is specific to `StrPack`. In Julia, the type of an array is restricted to the element type and its rank. (Rank is a count of how many indices it has.) The `StrPack` package uses the `@struct` macro to look for `[number]` after an `Array` declaration, and it manually creates the appropriate `bits` type in Julia for it. What you are *trying* to do is something like this:

```
@struct type MyType{n}
    values::Array{Float64}[n]
end
```

Unfortunately, `StrPack`'s `@struct` macro simply doesn't support type parameters, and it will choke on `MyType{n}` as it will not properly name a type.